# No suitable JDBC driver found for SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, java-web-start

I searched a lot of solutions, but none of them can solve my problem. I created a new project like below:
[image]

Note that I use Java 15. My main code to connect to SQL Server is below

```
package testDatabasePakage;

public class JavaConnectDB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true;";
        
        try
        {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("connected to Microsoft SQl Serever");
            
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Opps,theres an error\n ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
    }

}
```

Then I download the JDBC driver to connect to SQL Server, and I add it to my project:

[image]

From here I choose the third one, because I think it is the last version that suitable for Java 15. After that, I run project and I got the result is *"No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true;"*

Then I tried the other two, and got the same result like above. How do I add the JDBC driver suitable for my project?

Comment: You have to add the library to your classpath.

Comment: I add like the way you say. then Add External JARs...

Comment: The error message tells us something else ...

Comment: ```Opps,theres an error
 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true;
 at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
 at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
 at testDatabasePakage.JavaConnectDB.main(JavaConnectDB.java:15)```

Comment: And this error means, that the driver library is not in the classpath!

Comment: Can you show me the detail way to solve this problem? thank you

Comment: So you're using JRE 15 and have drivers for jre8, jre11 and jre14? Seems that the first thing to do with be to [get jre15 drivers](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc). Second thing would be to put them in a folder that's in your classpath.

Comment: It is probably not the cause of this error, but the URL should not have a trailing semicolon (`;`), see [Building the connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: How did you add the library to the project, because your screenshot doesn't actually show that you added the library to the build-path of your project.